# How can I get the length of a String in Swift 2.0?

Tags: string, swift, swift2

So far it was:

```
let string = "my example string"
if count(string) >= 3 { ... }
```

But now I get an error:

> `count` is unavailable: access the `count` property on the collection. Type `String` doesn't conform to protocol `CollectionType`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Oh, it is simple:

`string.characters.count`

Comment: You know what!! you posted the question on 9:03 AM and you got a brilliant vision at the time of 9:04 AM. Anyway still appreciate that !

Comment: @MohsinQureshi SO encourage to share your knowledge and post your question and answer same time.

Answer (score 2):

Again more simplified version

### In Swift 4.0 and Above

```
let strLength = string.count
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like that

```
let string = "my example string"
let length = string.characters.count
```

Because in Swift 2.0 **Apple** changed global functions to protocol extensions.